# STEP_COUNTER Android

Tags: android, android-sensors

Is it possible to clear the values from a STEP_COUNTER listener? I thought that you might be able to do it by unregistering the listener, but apparently the values are preserved. I'm registering a listener on the step_counter sensor, checking for changes, but then I want to flush or clear these values after a certain period of time. Any ideas?

Comment: missing the context - not the android Context :)

Comment: Using a listener to get the values when the step_counter returns a event.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently not but I did mine with a bit of math. I store the value of the count when the step_counter is initiated and then do some math.

```
mFinalCount = mCurrentCount;
mUpdatedCount = mCurrentCount - mFinalCount*2;
mNewCount = count - mUpdatedCount;
// count is the Float.valueOf(event.values[0]
```

Basically lets say the step counter is 300, the mUpdatedCount becomes -300 so now count(300) - mUpdatedCount(-300) = 0

I'm really new to android by the way but this worked for me.